# NodeJs Plugin Installation not found in Jenkins/configure

Tags: node.js, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to configure Jenkins to build my code using NodeJS Plugin. I have installed NodeJS plugin but NodeJS Installation are not available in System Configuration.

> ManageJenkins -> Configure System -> NodeJS installation (not
>   available)

I am running Jenkins on localhost.

What can I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you installed and followed the instruction mentioned in [node.js plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeJS+Plugin)? It is quite straight forward:

> 1. After installing the plugin, go to the global jenkins configuration
>      panel (JENKINS_HOME/configure or JENKINS_HOME/configureTools if
>      using jenkins 2), and add new NodeJS installations For every Nodejs
>      installation, you can choose to install some global npm packages.
> 2. Now, go to a job configuration screen, you will have 2 new items :
>      On the "Build environnment" section, you will be able to pick one of
>      the NodeJS installations to provide its bin/ folder to the PATH.
>      This way, during shell build scripts, you will have some npm
>      executables available to the command line (like bower or grunt)
> 3. Go to a job configuration screen, you will have 2 new items : On the
>      "Build environnment" section, you will be able to pick one of the
>      NodeJS installations to provide its bin/ folder to the PATH. This
>      way, during shell build scripts, you will have some npm executables
>      available to the command line (like bower or grunt)

You have to goto "/pluginManager/advanced" and run "check now" so that it will check the nodejs site and do the global install.

This will solve your problem

Comment: Hi, i can find the build environment section in jenkins, where is it?

Comment: @J.Doe did you find where the Build environment section is?

Comment: I want resolve an issue I have with Angular CLI, the ng command is not found

Comment: I have "Multibranch pipeline" so no "Build Environment" section.

After step #1 you can reference installations in pipeline as steps.
`nodejs(nodeJSInstallationName: '<installation_name>') {`